# Draw faded background/glow behind text

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a string with a background on a HTML5 canvas. I'm using the GMail favicon as an example, see this picture (from the labs settings page):
[image: Gmail favicon]

As you can see, the 8 in the picture has a white glow around it. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var notstring = notifications.toString();
var xpos = 14;
xpos -= (5 * notstring.length);

//Draw background
ctx.font = "15px sans-serif";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
//ctx.fillRect(xpos, 9, (5 * notstring.length) + 2, 7);
ctx.fillText(notstring, xpos - 1, 17);

//Draw text
ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText(notstring, xpos, 15);
```

As you can see I've tried drawing a rectangle behind it, that didn't look good, and text with a different font size, this looked better, but didn't give the fading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Faded out background" pretty much exactly describes a shadow, so use a shadow to get that effect! Play with the parameters until you're happy with the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksrfY/

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'lime';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
ctx.shadowBlur = 8;

ctx.font = '20pt Verdana';
ctx.fillText('8', 50, 50);
```

Set the offsets to 0,0 for a "perfect" background, like:

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksrfY/5/

Comment: Thank you, that was way easier than what I was planning :)

Comment: How do I remove the shadow before I draw other stuff? Setting shawdowBlur to 0 does not work. EDIT: This could also be due to me not clearing the last drawing right. I use ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 16, 16);

Answer (score 3):

Note that with a shadow only you cannot 'push' the glow very far from the edges of the text; the opacity drops off too quickly to be effective.

I would personally recommend using a stroke around text with a semi-transparent border before filling it solidly:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"; // 40% opaque white
ctx.lineWidth   = 10;                      // A nice fat border
ctx.strokeText(notstring, xpos, 15);

ctx.fillStyle   = "black";
ctx.fillText(notstring, xpos, 15);
```

If you find the 'hard' edge of the stroke to be too distracting you can still use the shadow blur to soften it up a little. You'll need to drop the opacity of the stroke (since it will also have a shadow under it):

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'red';               // full red shadow
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'; // 20% opaque red
ctx.shadowBlur  = 8;                   // soft edge
ctx.lineWidth   = 9;                   // wide border
ctx.strokeText(notstring, xpos, 15);
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;                    // turn off shadow before filling
ctx.fillText(notstring, xpos, 15);
```

You can see a live demo comparing just shadow, just stroke, and the combination here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ksrfY/11/

Comment: You saved the day!!